Remove unreferenced records from database
I have 3 tables in a MySQL database
user
--------------------------------------
user_id, (PK)
email



agreement_user
--------------------------------------
agreement_user_id, (PK)
user_id, (FK user.user_id)
details



contract
--------------------------------------
contract_id, (PK)
agreement_user_id, (FK agreement_user.agreement_user_id)
details

When a record from user table is deleted corresponding records from agreement_user table and contract table should also be deleted.
Unfortunately, the previous developer didn't implement it properly and only records from user table have been deleted, corresponding entries in agreement_user table and contract table are still there.
What should be the query to delete all those records from agreement_user table and contract table

The best long term fix here would be to add cascading deletion constraints on the tables, such that when a record from the user table gets deleted, all records from the 2 dependent tables also get deleted.
That being said, for an immediate fix, we could try a delete join here with the help of exists logic:
DELETE au, c
FROM agreement_user au
INNER JOIN contract c
    ON c.agreement_user_id = au.agreement_user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM user u
    WHERE u.user_id = au.user_id
);

See this SO question for details on how to alter your tables to add cascade delete constraints.
